# Python py2exe ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading glib\_glib.pyd

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, py2exe

I've got a problem with making a 1 file bundle(exe) with py2exe. When I run the program I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "keys.py", line 3, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "gtk\__init__.pyo", line 30, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "gobject\__init__.pyo", line 26, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "glib\__init__.pyo", line 22, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading glib\_glib.pyd
```

I have setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os, gtk

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
options = {'py2exe': {
    'includes': "cairo, pango, pangocairo, atk, gobject, gio",
    'bundle_files': 1,
    "excludes": "pywin, pywin.dialogs, pywin.dialogs.list, svn",
    "packages": "email, encodings",
    "dll_excludes": ["mswsock.dll, powrprof.dll, shfolder.dll, credui.dll, msvcp60.dll, secur32.dll"],
    "optimize":2,
    'compressed': True
    }
},
windows=[{'script':'keys.py'}],
zipfile = None,
)
```

When I do a `bundle_file = 3` every thing works fine but I can't get the `bundle_file` 1 or 2 make working without the `MemoryLoadLibrary` failure for glib.

I have reinstalled python2.7, installed pygtk all-in-one-bundle. Done a wipe of pygtk and tryied to install PyCairo, PyGObject, Glade and PyGtk from stand alones but still I get the same `Import Error`.

The `setup.py` is so big because I read so much about other pyd problems similar but not with glib so I was just adding to the setup every advice there was to make it work.

Is there a way to fix this `ImportError`? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

python is an interpreter based language so it keeps all the variables and temporary memory requirements only in the ram memory. Try in another system with higher memory or your can close the unwanted background process using the task manager.